# Жёлчный или желчный: историческое противостояние

Tags: фонетика

Слово «жёлчь» известно  в др.-рус. языке с 11 века в формах зълчь, золчь, желчь, жолчь,  оно родственно словам  жёлтый и зеленый.  Их общий и.-е. корень   ghel/ ghol, в дальнейшем же слова имели уже разные корневые гласные:  зелёный и жёлтый, жёлчь  (с 19 века, когда чередование Е/Ё стало отражаться  в устной и письменной речи).

Но казалось бы  закрепившаяся форма «жёлчь, жёлчный»  впоследствии стала оттесняться формой «желчь, желчный».  В словаре Аванесова (1987)  форма «желчь» дается как допустимая,  в словарях Резниченко (2009)  приводятся оба слова  «желчь и жёлчь», причем «желчь» ставится уже на первое место. В словаре Введенской (2012)  основной  опять считается форма «жёлчь», а «желчь» – разговорное слово.

Так что же происходит, с чем связаны эти колебания?  Можно ли считать «желчь, желчный» новой, прогрессивной формой, которая имеет какие-то преимущества перед прежним вариантом (а какие?). Или это безграмотность, с которой надо бороться?  И как говорите вы: жёлчный человек или желчный человек?

Примеры

"Слово «желчный» не зря появилось. «Желчный человек» ― мрачный, депрессивный. Русский язык ничего зря не закрепляет".  "Другой свидетель, пострадавший старичок, домовладелец , очевидно желчный человек" (Л. Толстой).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> В словаре Введенской (2012) основной
> опять считается форма «жёлчь», а
> «желчь» – разговорное слово.

Так же было в её словарях, думаю, и раньше.  Но… *"К сожалению, некоторая информация словаря, мягко говоря, устарела..."* (http://www.gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_1553 ).

> Так что же происходит?

Происходит постепенное забывание того, как должно было бы произноситься слово *жёлчь.* Причина -- необязательность употребления на письме буквы ***Ё.*** Ведь если написано "желчь", многие ли полезут в словарь, чтобы узнать, как эта *желчь* должна произноситься?

> Можно ли считать «желчь, желчный»
> новой, прогрессивной формой...

Ну если она вытесняет старую норму, то конечно можно.

Но вытесняет не во всех значениях слова *желчный.* Так, "Большой орфоэпический словарь…"  (М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткин, Р. Ф. Касаткина. Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты. М., «АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА», 2012) допускает обе формы -- и *желчный* и *жёлчный,* если говорить о человеке, о его характере. Но только форму *жёлчный* (с пометой: *! неправ. ж[э]лчный* ), если речь идёт о ж[о]лчном пузыре.

> И как говорите вы: жёлчный человек или
> желчный человек?

Слово не из моего лексикона. Но если б понадобилось прочитать "желчный", прочитал бы как *ж[э]лчный.*

Comment: Спасибо за интересную информацию. Думаю, что здесь дело не только в обозначении буквы Ё, хотя и это сыграло свою роль (ведь слово жёлтый, как и многие другие слова, тоже пишется через Е). Мне кажется, что причина в слове  "желчный", имеющем ПЕРЕНОСНОЕ значение: оно и само стало произноситься через Е в соответствии с письмом, и повлияло на исходное слово с прямым значением. Поэтому в новом словаре термин "жёлчный пузырь" с обязательным Ё противопоставляется "желчному характеру", где еще наблюдается колебание.

Comment: Думаю, тут ещё один нюанс: ср. жёлтый vs желтуха.